# How can i bind a key to list snippets in sublime text 3?

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext3

Can i bind a key, like command + shift + i to show snippets in current context just like command + shift + p , type "snippets:" do ?

thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your user keybindings.

`{ "keys": ["super+shift+i"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": "snippet:"} }`

Answer (score 1):

This is a tiny tid-bit expansion on the answer above.  Thanks for that answer, I had been looking for this as well.

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+i"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": "Snippet: "} }
```

Note the "text": has a capital 'S' and a trailing space included...with this, it shows the shortcut keys in the Tools menu beside Snippets...

i.e.

Snippets...             Win+Shift+I